# 'unsafe' functions in C++/CLI wrapper?

Tags: pointers, c++-cli, wrapper

Firstly allow me to thank everyone who helped me over the last few days, I finally have a C++/CLI wrapper for my C++ class, which I can create instances of in C#, thankyou StackOverflow!

Some of these functions take pointers as parameters however, when using PInvoke you can just declare the function as unsafe and then call it with the ref keyword like so

```
[DllImport("DLLName.dll")]
public static unsafe extern someFunc(ref int);

// then in main... 
int a;
someFunc(ref a);
```

but how do I go about wrapping C++ functions that take pointer paramaters in C++/CLI so that I can call them from C#?

Thanks.

EDIT - My function signiatures are

```
UINT Init(char* info[], int amount, int ID1, int ID2)       
UINT GetJPValues(SJPInfo* jpi, int iTimeoutMS)
UINT GetNums(int amount, int* out, int iTimeoutMS)
UINT GetJPWValues(SJP* jp, int ID, UINT stake, int iTimeoutMS)
UINT Confirm(bool *bConfirmed, int ID, int iTimeoutMS)
```

JPInfo and SJP are C++ structs that contain only data, I've created C# versions that are packed the same way as their C++ counterparts but I'm also not sure how I can take the C# structs as a parameter to the C++/CLI functions which then call the C++ functions.

EDIT 2 - Forgot to mention the structs are just filled with data from a winsock recv in the C++ code, so they could probably be passed in as char*?

Comment: What is your actual C++ function signature?

Comment: There are several that take pointers I'll add them to the post

Comment: If you want a complete answer, you'll need to also post the definitions of `SJPInfo` and `SJP` (and any other UDTs they use), and the semantics of which arguments are effectively const (i.e., which arguments will be written to, and which will only be read from).

Answer (score 1):

From experience I always keep the interface to simple types like int,double etc (I did also use String^ in the interface and simply converted to std::string using code that's easy to find on the Internet).

This does tend to mean exposed functions in the wrapper class take more parameters but it's easy to understand and most importantly it works!

Comment: The structs define the packet structures though, so I will need to pass in pointers to structs, I've been doing a bit of research and IntPtr exists in both C# and C++/CLI, and as far as I can see can point to any type, could I use this?

To clarify, the structs passed in are filled in the C++ code with whatever was received from the windows socket